# Force ant to use specific java version on Windows

Tags: java, windows, ant, runtime, version

I use a simple build.xml from the internet with no java/executable specified as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="the project" default="compile" basedir=".">

    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="bin.dir" location="bin" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <!-- Create the time stamp -->
        <tstamp />
        <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
    </target>


    <target name="clean" description="remove intermediate files">
        <delete dir="${bin.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the Java source code to class files">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${bin.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Below are a few java versions on my Windows apart from others:

```
where java
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
G:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe
```

I wish to use this specific version of java with ant `G:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe`. However, ant continues to use a different below JDK version.

```
C:\Users\HOME>ant -Dant.build.javac.target=1.8.0_301 -Dant.build.javac.source=1.8.0_301 -Dant.java.version=1.8.0_301 -v |  findstr /I "java"
Detected Java version: 10 in: G:\jdk-10

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\HOME\build.xml:25: srcdir "C:\Users\HOME\src" does not exist!
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.collectFileListFromSourcePath(Javac.java:1144)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1086)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)

Total time: 0 seconds
    [javac] C:\Users\HOME\build.xml:25: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
```

Ignoring the error as I'm just concerned with checking which version of java is used by my ant.

I also tried `C:\Users\HOME>ant -Dant.build.javac.target=1.8 -Dant.build.javac.source=1.8 -v |  findstr /I "java"` which also did not help.

I'm open to different answers but would prefer solutions to pass arguments to ant commands to use the desired JDK.

The idea is to switch between `java versions` when using `ant` to build different applications on my host.

The sub-version of java is important so I may wish to choose between java versions `1.8.0_145` and `1.8.0_301`

Comment: Have you tried to `SET JAVA_HOME=G:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_301` before running `ant`? And if that doesn't work, maybe `SET PATH=G:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin;%PATH%`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos `SET JAVA_HOME` works. Thank you ... However, still interested to know if there is any `-D` parameters to force which java to use?

Comment: No, there isn't. And setting the source/target compatibility does not affect which JDK is used, it affects which bytecode version is emitted (and which Java features are available in source).

Comment: `-D` parameters usually apply to the `java` executable, after the startup script has determined where it is! So, I would say no, `-D` parameters will not have the effect you want. What they probably do (haven't used Ant for many years) is set the compiler compatibility required by your code, but again *after* the `java` executable has been located.

Comment: I would consider using [JEnv for Windows](https://github.com/FelixSelter/JEnv-for-Windows) and then you can get it to automatically use a particular version depending upon which project folder you're running in.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use javac from a different JDK version to the default by specifying a forked javac task:

```
<javac 
     ...
     fork="yes" executable="${mycompiler}"
```

Run with path to a different javac.exe:

```
ant -Dmycompiler=C:\java\jdk-14\bin\javac.exe targets
ant -Dmycompiler=C:\java\jdk-17\bin\javac.exe targets
```

You may of course need additional ant settings to ensure that the default source/release is compatible for alternative JDK.

IMO though you'd be better off fixing your login / environment so that there isn't multiple java.exe versions when you type `where java`. It is very easy to configure CMD.EXE or Windows Terminal to setup for a specific JDK, allowing build from any version without changing the command line to `ant`.